# Can my friend from Pakistan work as a contracted worker for US company, since H1B visas are not being issued in us?

Tags: united-states, visa, remote-work, independent-contractor, pakistan

My good friend wants to work for my company in the US, he's in Pakistan currently. He does not need to be physically present in the US. He is not a US citizen he's from Pakistan. any way for him to be a contracted worker and for my company to hire him?

Again he could be a remote worker from Pakistan, he's a programmer. he does not need to physically be in the united states. Thank you guys!

Comment: Yes, this is totally common and normal.  The person does the work, sends an emailing stating how much money you owe him, and your company sends the money to them. It's 100% normal and OK!

Comment: If it would be in India, The guy has to process his own income-tax himself as self-assessment. He needs to get a [GST number](https://www.bajajfinserv.in/insights/what-is-goods-and-service-tax-identification-number) against which he submits the tax. He has to create a commercial-invoices for the payment charge (the export service).  He also needs to issue a [FIRC](https://freeinvoicebuilder.com/firc-receive-foreign-inward-remittance-certificate-india/) from the bank in which compensation get credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. He can offer his services as a contractor. He will have to sort out his own taxes in Pakistan like any self-employed person would.

There may be some knock-on effects, for example in some countries banks are reluctant to accept income in non-local currencies when applying for a mortgage. Also they will need some way to get paid, ideally a US account to make it easier for the employer, or at least an international one that accepts payment in USD.

Otherwise it's just like doing local contracting, the fact that it's a US company makes little difference.

Comment: Probably worth explicitly stating that no visa is required.